# Solving for all values of k if a quadratic equation containing it has two distinct real roots

Tags: roots, quadratics

The equation $$x^2-2kx+1=0$$ has two distinct real roots. Find the set of all possible values of *k*.

What I did:

1. $$b-4ac=0$$
2. $$(-2k)^2-4=0$$
3. $$(-2k)^2=4$$
4. $$-2k=2$$
5. $$k=(-1)$$

From this, I'm unsure where to go-- it says *find the set*. I understand that $$k=1$$ as well as *-1* but how is that a set? Like I think the question wants me to give my answer in set notation but I'm unsure how to do that.

Comment: This gives equal roots, not distinct roots

Comment: If $k=1$ you do **not** have two distinct real roots. You condition must be $$(-2k)^2-4>0$$

Answer (score 1):

For distinct real roots,
$$b^2-4ac\gt0$$
$$(-2k)^2-4\gt0$$
$$k^2-1\gt0$$
$$(k+1)(k-1)\gt0$$
$$k\in(-\infty,-1)\cup(1,\infty)$$

Answer (score 0):

solving the given equation we obtain $$x=k\pm\sqrt{k^2-1}$$ thus we obtain two real solutions if $$k^2>1$$ or $$(k-1)(k+1)>0$$
can you proceed?

Answer (score 0):

The values of $k$ are precisely the solutions of $\Delta>0$ that's $k^2-1>0$, which gives $k<-1\vee k>1$.

Answer (score 0):

The quadratic formula uses $\sqrt{b^2-4ac}$.  For there to be $2$ distinct real roots, $b^2-4ac\gt 0$, otherwise if $b^2-4ac=0$ the two roots are real but the same, and if $b^2-4ac\lt 0$ both roots are complex.

So we need to find the set of solution to $b^2-4ac\gt 0$, which, using the equation given, is solutions to $(-2k)^2-4\gt0$, which simplifies to $k^2>1$ or $|k|>1$.

So the set $S$ of solutions is $S=\{k: |k|\gt1\}$.